# Transfer cacerts file to another das

Tags: certificate, glassfish, direct-attached-storage

I was wondering if its possible to transfer the cacerts.jks file to another glassfish DAS machine? The idea is to synchronize both das machines without having to import every certificate manually.

Thanks